# OpenID Connect Provider implementation

Tags: dotnetopenauth, openid-connect, openid-provider

Is there any sample of implementation of OpenID Connect Provider in .NET?

DotNetOpenAuth doesn't seem to support this standard.

Comment: Did you ever find any way to implement a datasource or provider in .Net?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IdentityServer is an openid connect provider. There are lots of samples of relying parties, provider configurations and a resource server api. See here for the examples: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/

It seems to currently be the only "certified" open source .NET (C#) implementation. See http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

I would expect Microsoft to release their OP pretty soon, named WAAD - Windows Azure Active Directory Server:  http://www.gluu.co/waad-interop

Are you sure you need an OpenID Provider? If you need Relying Party code, I recently saw this quick article: http://www.gluu.co/simple-connect-client

If you really need an OP, perhaps you should consider OX: http://ox.gluu.org

Who really cares what language the OP is written in? What you want is an easy way to administer the thing... and OX provides an excellent management Web UI (oxTrust).